# What is INSTANCE in HibernateUtil?

Tags: java, hibernate, instance

I am new to Hibernate framework of Java.
I have a code of `HibernateUtil` class, I didn't understand from where the `INSTANCE` came.
It holds the onstance of `HibernateUtil` class, how???

The code is this...

```
import java.util.Properties;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistryBuilder;

public enum HibernateUtil {

INSTANCE;   // what about this???
public static SessionFactory sessionFactory = null;

private synchronized SessionFactory initialiseSessionFactory() {

    if (sessionFactory == null) {
        Configuration config = new Configuration();

        config.addAnnotatedClass(demo1.class);
        config.addAnnotatedClass(demo2.class);
        config.configure();

        //get the properties from Hibernate configuration file
        Properties configProperties = config.getProperties();
        ServiceRegistryBuilder serviceRegisteryBuilder = new ServiceRegistryBuilder();
        ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = serviceRegisteryBuilder.applySettings(configProperties).buildServiceRegistry();
        sessionFactory = config.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);

    }
    return sessionFactory;
}

public Session getSession() {
    Session hibernateSession = null;

    if (sessionFactory == null) {
        hibernateSession = initialiseSessionFactory().openSession();

    } else {
        hibernateSession = sessionFactory.openSession();
           }
    return hibernateSession;
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HibernateUtil is implementing the singleton pattern: there can be only one instance of that class, and that instance is HibernateUtil.INSTANCE.

Comment: but there is no `INSTANSE = new HibernateUtil();`, then from where where it came, and why HibernateUtil is "enum"??

Comment: do you give me a link from where I can understand this thing...about enums.

Answer (score 0):

An `enum` in Java is actually a class. One that implicitly extends `java.lang.Enum`. The special syntax you see at `INSTANCE`; is a declaration of an enum constant. This is going to be used to make an instance of your enum class which can be referred to in code.